# How does my computer suspend?

Tags: suspend, acpi

Trying to understand how suspend works in 10.10.

http://git.webconverger.org/?p=home.git;a=blob;f=.bashrc;h=8ba57b877e31a03c5f0b1675b42f747d81dd31ad;hb=HEAD#l31

I use an `alias suspend='sudo /etc/acpi/sleep.sh && sudo alsactl init 0`

The `alsactl` bit is to re-init my sound card which sometimes does not come out of suspend correctly.

And then:

`/etc/acpi/sleep.sh` -> `/usr/sbin/pm-suspend` -> `/usr/lib/pm-utils/bin/pm-action` -> `/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions`

Irony is `/usr/lib/pm-utils/bin/pm-action` claims to be "Simple suspend script".

Still don't know how it works. I think I directly used `s2ram` before.

Comment: I know I'm not explaining much but you could put your `alsactl` command in its own script in `/etc/acpi/resume.d/` and it'll run on-wake.

Comment: Update: I simply use `sudo systemctl suspend` now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `gnome-power-manager` tool listens for suspend button events, and spawns `pm-suspend`. Extensive detail about how `pm-suspend` operates can be found in the `man pm-suspend` command output. The quick version:

1. `/etc/pm/config.d` is scanned for files that define environment variables.
2. Each of the scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` and `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` are called in order with the "suspend" argument.
3. The system is put to sleep via the defined interface module. By default, this is the kernel suspend interface: `echo -n "mem" >/sys/power/state`. See `/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions` where `do_suspend` is defined.
4. The system wakes up.
5. Each of the scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` and `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` are called in reverse order with the "resume" argument.

If you need to add a script to the stack, I would suggest adding it to `/etc/pm/sleep.d` and name it something that does not conflict with other scripts, and make sure it processes the "suspend"/"resume" argument.

For debugging, see `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` as well as the man page which has more information on how to do testing.

Comment: Thanks kees, though what out of interest, what *exactly* is the command to trigger the "kernel suspend" in step 3?

Comment: I've updated to include that detail too now.