# How to disable cd drive check after resuming from suspend?

Tags: 11.04, suspend, cd-drive

After resuming from suspend, my laptop performs a check on the CD drive. I currently do not use it that much, so I am wondering if there is a way I can disable the said check after my laptop resumes its status from suspend mode?

I have looked at [how it suspends](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8243/how-does-my-computer-suspend), but I don't know what program I should look at in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`.

Comment: What is the reason for that? most systems (at least in my knowledge) do not do that unless there is something in it before suspend.

Comment: What do you mean "performs a check"?

Comment: A click in the CD drive.  The same noise we hear after inserting a disk.

Comment: I suspect it's in the hdparm script somewhere, but I don't see a good way to disable just the optical drives.

Comment: Perhaps a BIOS setting? Have you tried there?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling CDROM

`mv  /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/cdrom/cdrom.ko /root`

Answer (score 0):

If you check your system Bios on startup, check your boot order.  I am not a big techie but that would be the first thing I would check.  Move it down the boot order so it hits your hard drive first.  Good luck.

Comment: I could be wrong but I doubt this is BIOS driven as wake-from-suspend tends to be well after the boot sequence (unlike a fresh boot or a wake-from-hibernate).