# how to speed up the reconnection of WLAN after sleep

Tags: sleep, wireless

I am using an HP netbook with a Broadcom wl-card. I use the STA driver. After waking up from sleep it takes normally 30 seconds to be reconnected to my WLAN. Using the command 
`sudo iwlist scanning` 
the reconnection process starts immediately. I wrote a script
`echo $Password | sudo -S $iwlist scanning` 
and start it via a starter from the desktop, thus reducing the time to 15 sec.
Is there a way to start the script automatically and preventing the terminal from popping up.

Answer (score 1):

First, have a look at [how your computer suspends/resumes](https://askubuntu.com/a/9533/236). According to that you might adapt your script and put it into `/etc/pm/sleep.d`. The script should look like

```
#!/bin/sh
case "${i}" in
  resume)
  $DO_SOMETHING
  ;;
esac
```

A second (and better) possibility is to modify `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`. There are some scripts, important are `55NetworkManager` and `60_wpa_supplicant`. The numbers 55 and 60 are a kind of priority. The lower the number the earlier the suspend script is executed. At resume the scripts are run in reverse order.

So I would suggest copying the scripts from `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` to `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` and play around with the first number. Maybe there are some dependencies on your system. You will have to find out through some experimenting.